# hook_form_alter changes array, but is not rendering in contact form

Tags: drupal, contact-form, hook-form-alter

I use hook_form_contact_site_form_alter to alter the Conact Form. Everyting works fine when I change the array, for example:

```
  $form['firstname'] = array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('FirstName'),
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#required' => true

  );
```

dpm($form); shows me this:

[image]

So, thats perfect

... but nothing renders! Its still the good old default contact form:
[image]

I was thinking, that maybe another hook overrides mine, or that I have to tell Drupal to rebuild the form. I haven't found anything usefuls in the API Reference yet.

Maybe somebody else had the same problem, or knows a good method to debug?

Thanks in Advance

btw. I had the contact_forms module installed, but uninstalled it again, maybe this is related.

Comment: mmm, if you think is there aother module are execute and override a form, try to update weight ... look to this 
https://www.drupal.org/node/110238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `form_alter`, don't forget to pass the first argument as a reference (`&$form`) or your `$form` variable will not be modified once your function has been executed.

```
function hook_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

}
```

Comment: I knew it was a one character answer. Thanks a lot.